# Recent Downloaded Emails Not Showing in Inbox folder Outlook 2010

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have searched the web and spend hours trying to figure out this strange behaviour of Outlook 2010,

My client has this problem with her Outlook 2010 since yesterday, the mails download but do not appear anywhere in Outlook 2010. The download bar shows mails are downloading, mails are then removed from the server, but no where to be found in Outlook.

There's 1 email account, and then 5 PST files of which one belongs and is linked correctly to the email account.

I can also search in outlook for the mails, but nothing shows up, I also re-indexed Outlook and still can't find the mails. I tried sending a mail which sends fine, the mail is also stored in the sent items, so the problem is only when receiving emails

The solutions I've tried and found on http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/outlook-2010-receive-messages-but-cant-see-them/dabdc9f1-c46b-427f-be2f-f42b56d31171?page=4 don't help with my problem, I tried the following solutions on the link above

> File>Account Settings>Data Files>Select the email you want to see the
>   emails from and click "Set as Default" then restart out look and the
>   inbox should have your emails in them if not hit send and receive.
>
> ---
>
> In Outlook 2010, Go to "View" tab, Under "Change View" change the
>   Views, that will reset the settings you have.
>
> ---
>
> More on the filter solution. If you are not showing a "filter applied"
>   indication in the lower left corner, try this. Highlight your inbox
>   and select the view tab at the top. Next click on View Settings on the
>   ribbon and select Filter. Select the Advanced tab at the top of the
>   window and if you see a filter set under the Find items that match
>   these criteria then remove it. Click OK out of all the screens and you
>   should see your phantom e-mail appear in your Inbox. Hope this helps
>   someone!

Also tried to run  **outlook /cleanviews** with no effect

No anti virus system is installed, so that can't block mails

**Operating System**: Windows 7

**Outlook** : MS Outlook 2010

Any advise help would be highly appreciated, the client also can't afford to loose the mails, so deleting accounts etc is risky.

Comment: No antivirus system is installed? You might want to start there. Verify the system is clean of viruses and malware before chasing your tail on this problem. You may want to check out [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/q/100360/97028).

Comment: @CharlieRB - Thank you for raising the point - Yes will have a look, if the system is clean, what else do you suggest

Comment: Have you tried using System Restore to a date prior to yesterday? Is this Outlook 2010 or 2007? You've referenced both. Also, what type of connection? Is this Exchange or POP/SMTP, etc?

Comment: @CharlieRB - Totally forgot to mention, it's POP3 port 110 and SMTP port 25, haven't tried system restore, if I perform a System restore will the Ghost mails / data the client received today be lost?

Comment: System Restore should not effect the data file for outlook. *"System Restore can return your PC's system files and programs to a time when everything was working fine, potentially preventing hours of troubleshooting headaches. It won't affect your documents, pictures, or other data."* per [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore)

Comment: @CharlieRB - I will definitely try the system restore when client gets back, thanks

Comment: @CharlieRB - Unfortunately System Restore did not work also no virusses on the machine

Comment: Are there any rules being applied when messages arrive?

Comment: @CharlieRB - Unfortunately not, I deleted the mail profile and re-added the profile which solved the problem, only issue I have now is the new mails are now showing, but the clients needs all the mails that downloaded yesterday but aren't showing

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me with Outlook 2010.

1)  In the left hand navigation pane, click on (highlight) the .pst file where the "missing" emails should be showing. Or, if the emails are just "missing" from  a folder or subfolder, click on that folder or subfolder.

2)  Click on the "View" tab on the top of the Outlook window.

3)  On the far left side of the ribbon in the "Current View" section, click on "Change View."

4)  There should be 4 options:

```
 Hide Messages
 Compact
 Single
 Preview
```

5)  "Hide Messages" is probably the option presently applied, so click on the option you would prefer instead, and your emails should appear in your email window in the format you have just selected.

6)  If "Hide Messages" does not appear as an option, click on any option other than the one presently applied and let the drop down box disappear. Your emails should appear in the email window in the format you have just selected. Then click on "Change View" again and choose your original format (assuming that this format is still what you want), or choose another option altogether. Your emails should now appear in the email window in the original or newly-selected format.

Comment: This is one of those things that comes up every so often in my support job but I never remember how to get to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue with Outlook 2010. All you need to do is delete the outlook profile and recreate it. Open up control panel > Mail > Delete your existing profile by selecting profile name and remove/delete. Open up Outlook and create the profile again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For exchange servers and some IMAP then, yes, Outlook recreates the OST file if it is deleted by the user. For email accounts using PST files then the user needs to create a new Outlook file and copy the old emails across and configure the settings so all email goes to the new file. The old one can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find my hidden emails by selecting Change View, selecting Preview, after which the hidden messages appeared in the preview list.

I then went back to compact view, which is my normal view setting.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me:

go to account settings.
choose Change Folder
under Personal Folders\Inbox make sure that it points to the correct .pst file because in my case fir some reason it was pointing to the dfault .pst file not my imported .pst file that I set in the Data Files tap.
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this it worked for me too:

go to account settings. choose Change Folder under Personal Folders\Inbox make sure that it points to the correct .pst file because in my case fir some reason it was pointing to the dfault .pst file not my imported .pst file that I set in the Data Files tap. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and I have solution that worked for me.

For some reason **email password was the problem**. I could send email, but I couldn't find received ones. Here's how to fix :

- Go to `cpanel`
- Email accounts
- Password and Authentication
- Change password for that email account.

Use new password when you are creating new email account in outlook for that email account.

Answer (score -1):

Turn off or disable all your Rules. It solved emails going to ALL MAIL and bypassing INBOX. Outlook rules are a pain. Thunderbird has a much easier way to create rules.